# EHCache Local TransactionManager timeout on removal

Tags: java, caching, transactions, ehcache

I am working on a project to incorporate ehCache. Currently I am writing JUnit tests to test the various behaviours. When adding a transaction manager I started seeing timeout issues on certain calls.

Currently using eHcache 2.10.5 but also tried 2.8.4
Below is my xml

```
    <cache name="ehCache_1"
       maxElementsInMemory="20"
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToLiveSeconds="50"
       timeToIdleSeconds="10"
       transactionalMode="local">
```

Below here is my JUnit

```
@Test
public void testEHCacheIssue(){
    try{
        Ehcache ehCache_1 = ehCacheManager.getCache("ehCache_1");
        transactionManager = ehCacheManager.getTransactionController();
        transactionManager.setDefaultTransactionTimeout(15);

        transactionManager.begin();
        ehCache_1.put(new Element("1", new TestElementPerson(1, "firstName1", "lastName1","email1@test.com",1234)));
        transactionManager.commit();

        transactionManager.begin();
        ehCache_1.put(new Element("2", new TestElementPerson(2, "firstName3", "lastName3","email3@test.com",1234)));
        transactionManager.commit();

        transactionManager.begin();
        ehCache_1.get("1");
        transactionManager.commit();

        transactionManager.begin(); 
        ehCache_1.remove("1");//Timeout happens here
        transactionManager.commit();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.error("There was an exception", ex);
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Which throws the below error on the remove:

There was an exception

> net.sf.ehcache.transaction.TransactionTimeoutException: transaction
>   [3] timed out     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.transaction.local.LocalTransactionStore.assertNotTimedOut(LocalTransactionStore.java:108)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.transaction.local.LocalTransactionStore.remove(LocalTransactionStore.java:391)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.AbstractCopyingCacheStore.remove(AbstractCopyingCacheStore.java:110)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.TxCopyingCacheStore.remove(TxCopyingCacheStore.java:33)
>     at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeInternal(Cache.java:2426)     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:2331)  at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:2249)  at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:2227)

I notice that if I do anything that involves put or remove on an already existing key I get this issue. I know the Transaction Manager puts locks on the key between the begin and commit and that the Transaction Manager's threads tend to timeout sometimes in concurrent environments, but Im unsure how I could use the Transaction Manager if it holds a lock on the object's key for any serious period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout problem was related to not having hashCode/toString defined for the objects we were caching as is requested in the documentation.

https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions.html#requirements

Adding hashCode/toString solved the issue for myself.